# Default landing uiview for tab based application

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have an app with 2 tabs.

In the first tab, uiview1 two buttons. Button 1 adds an item into an object into the array every time it is pressed. Button 2 is a button which segues to uiview2. uiview2 has uitableview, which contains the amount of objects in the array, and a button which segues into uiview3.

I've noticed that the default manner in which the application works is that the current view of the tab persists, after navigating to a different tab. I'd like to create a default landing uiview.

I'd like to make it so that if I navigate away from tab1 and back, based on the number of objects in the array, the view that loads is either uiview1 (where you must create an object) or uiview2 (where

pseudo-code

```
if (moving from tab2 to tab1)
{
    if(number of objects > 0)
    {
        load uiview2;
    }
    else 
    { 
        load uiview1; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against breaking the default behavior of the UITabBarController, but if you really want to do this you could implement the [UITabBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/) methods.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    // logic here

    // this is how you could "pop" to one of the two view controllers
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:uiviewcontroller1 animated:NO];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:uiviewcontroller2 animated:NO];
}
```